# how set Month as string in Python datetime

Tags: python

I found this example how to set time and covert back to readable form

```
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17)
print(x.strftime("%Y %b %d"))
```

My question is how to set new date with `Month` as string ?
Is it possible ? Is there some parameter/function  for this ?

`y = datetime.datetime(2020, May, 17)`

Update:
How can I show difference between two times only in days ?

```
x = datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 17)
now=datetime.now()
print('Time difference:', str(x-now))
```

Current output is :
`Time difference: 416 days, 9:37:06.470952`

OK , I got it

`print('Time difference:', (x-now).days)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function provided which accepts a string argument to specify the month. But you can use the `strptime` class method to *parse* a string that contains a month name into a `datetime` value.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("2020 May 17", "%Y %b %d")
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 0, 0)
```

If you really need *just* the month as a string, and already have the other components as integers, you can parse just the month, extract the month number, and create a second object:

```
>>> year = 2020
>>> month = "May"
>>> day = 17
>>> datetime(year, datetime.strptime(month, "%b").month, day)
```

but I would recommend constructing a complete string first and parsing that.

```
datetime.strptime(f'{year} {month} {day}', "%Y %b %d")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `datetime.datetime.strptime()` you can parse a month using the [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

- `%b` for locale’s abbreviated name like `Mar` or
- `%B` for locale’s full name like `March` or
- `%m` for zero-padded decimal number like `03`,

These format codes also apply to `datetime.datetime.strftime()`.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime

x = datetime.strptime("Mar","%b")

print(x.strftime("%m"))
```

Comment: Great explanation of *format codes* for moth and their usage. Hope you don't mind my improving edit.